# Twilio outgoing call to recipient with call screening (Google voice)

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a working service, where we do outgoing calls something like this.

```
$sid = getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
$token = getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create("+14155551212", // to
                        "+14155551212", // from
                        ["url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3"]
               );

print($call->sid);
```

The issue is when the recipient has call screening, the callback to the URL parameter is done as soon as the screening starts (with callbackstatus "in-progress"!), which means we have to add a pause in the response.

```
<Response>
    <Pause length="10"/>
    <Say>
This is an important message
</Say>
    <Gather action="https://xxx" method="GET" timeout="15" speechTimeout="auto" numDigits="1" input="dtmf speech">
        <Say>Please press 1 followed by the pound sign or say confirm to confirm your appointment</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Redirect method="GET">https://xxx</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Is there some way to bypass the screening or have the system not start the response  in screening?

EDIT:
I've added the AMD options and it seems to be correctly somewhat working. Right now the only issue that remains is when calling in to Google Voice, when there's call screening, my added voice recording start reading before the recipient actually answers

```
$call = $client->calls->create(
          $to, $from,
          array(
            "url" => $url,
            "statusCallback" => $statusURL,
            "statusCallbackMethod" => 'POST',
            "machineDetection" => "DetectMessageEnd",
            "machineDetectionTimeout" => 5
          )
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [answering machine detection (AMD)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection).

You can make a call with AMD enabled by setting the `MachineDetection` parameter to `Enable` or `DetectMessageEnd`.

```php
$call = $twilio->calls
               ->create("+14155551212", // to
                        "+14155551212", // from
                        [
                           "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/classic.mp3",
                           "machineDetection" => "Enabled"
                        ]
               );
```

When you use the `MachineDetection` parameter the request to your `url` will include an `AnsweredBy` parameter. [From the docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#machinedetection):

> Use `Enable` if you would like Twilio to return an [`AnsweredBy`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#webhook-parameters) value as soon as it identifies the called party. This is useful if you would like to take a specific action — for example, connect to an agent, play a message) — for a human but hang up on a machine.
>
> If you would like to leave a voicemail on an answering machine, specify `DetectMessageEnd`. In this case, Twilio will return an [`AnsweredBy`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#webhook-parameters) immediately when a human is detected but for an answering machine, AnsweredBy is returned only once the end of the greeting is reached, usually indicated by a beep.

There is also an option for [asynchronous AMD](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#asyncamd). With asynchronous detection your `url` is called immediately as if a normal call, but once Twilio has performed the detection an [asynchronous webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#asyncamdstatuscallback) is made to a different URL and you can use the callback data to decide whether to update the call.

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. But I'm still having issues. I've added the AMD options, but it's refusing understanding Google Voice call screening. Meaning if I call in as a unknown number, the voice recoding I've attached starts reading before the recipient even picks up. Not sure if it's an issue with Google Voice or not at this moment

Comment: I see you've tried experimenting with `machineDetectionTimeout`. Have you tried any of the other [tuning parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#optional-api-tuning-parameters) like `machineDetectionSpeechThreshold`?

Comment: Not yet, I hoped the defaults would give us a the best shot at this working without false matches. But I'll play around with the parameters including the one You suggested, thanks!